# ¿Como listar las direcciones MAC con un script en bash?

Tags: bash, shell, macos, terminal, shell-script

Quiero listar las direciones MAC con un script en la terminal de MacOS, pero el codigo no me funciona:

```
interfaces=$(networksetup -listallhardwareports | awk '/Hardware Port:/ {print $3}')

for interface in $interfaces; do
  mac_address=$(ifconfig $interface | awk '/ether/{print $2}')
  echo "$mac_address"
  echo
done
```

Comment: ¿Para qué usas networksetup? Parece que lo consigues sin él: `ifconfig |awk '/ether/{print $2}'`